# How to collect all variables as a list in tensorflow grouped as a function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, gan

I am trying to reproduce the cGAN network architecture introduced on the recent [paper deep video portrait(2018, Standford)](https://web.stanford.edu/~zollhoef/papers/SG2018_DeepVideo/paper.pdf)

I have defined `Generator` as `T(x)` following the notation of the paper.

And T(x) refer the above listed `operation blocks`, such as `conv_down(), conv_upsample(), biLinearDown() and finalTanH()`.

I had notated their scope with 'with tf.variable_scope()' syntax.

While I am comprising a loss and optimizer, found that I need to collect those Generator related variables all together since we are going to train with two differet optimizers, one for the discriminator and one for the generator.

Discriminator is upto my co-lleague so it's not my concern, so I just remains it as psheudo.

However, I 'd like to make a list of variables defined in `T(x)` in my code.

How can I do this? Any help?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# hyper-params 
learning_rate = 0.0002
epochs = 250
batch_size = 16
N_w = 11 #number of frames concatenated together 
channels = 9*N_w
drop_out = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lambda_ = 100 #for Weighting of T_loss    

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Graph().as_default():

    def conv_down(x, N, count): #Conv [4x4, str_2] > Batch_Normalization > Leaky_ReLU
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_down_{}_count{}".format(N, count)): #N == depth of tensor 
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
            x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
            x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x) #for conv_down, implement leakyReLU
        return x

    def conv_upsample(x, N, drop_rate, count):
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_upsamp_{}_count{}".format(N,count)) :
            #up
            with tf.variable_scope("conv_up_count{}".format(count)):
                x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, N, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
                x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
                with tf.variable_scope("convdrop_{}".format(count)):
                    if drop_rate is not 0:
                        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
                x = tf.nn.relu(x)

            #refine1
            with tf.variable_scope("refine1"):
                x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
                x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
                with tf.variable_scope("rf1drop_out_{}".format(count)):
                    if drop_rate is not 0:
                        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
                x = tf.nn.relu(x)

            #refine2
            with tf.variable_scope("refine2"):
                x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
                x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
                with tf.variable_scope("rf2drop_out{}".format(count)):
                    if drop_rate is not 0:
                        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
                x = tf.nn.relu(x)

        return x     

    def biLinearDown(x, N):
        return tf.image.resize_images(x, [N, N])

    def finalTanH(x):
        with tf.variable_scope("tanh"):
            x = tf.nn.tanh(x)
        return x

    def T(x):  
        #channel_output_structure
        down_channel_output = [64, 128, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512]
        up_channel_output= [512, 512, 512, 512, 256, 128, 64, 3]
        biLinearDown_output= [32, 64, 128] #for skip-connection 

        #down_sampling
        conv1 = conv_down(x, down_channel_output[0], 1) 
        conv2 = conv_down(conv1, down_channel_output[1], 2)
        conv3 = conv_down(conv2, down_channel_output[2], 3)
        conv4 = conv_down(conv3, down_channel_output[3], 4)
        conv5 = conv_down(conv4, down_channel_output[4], 5)
        conv6 = conv_down(conv5, down_channel_output[5], 6)
        conv7 = conv_down(conv6, down_channel_output[6], 7)
        conv8 = conv_down(conv7, down_channel_output[7], 8)

        #upsampling 
        dconv1 = conv_upsample(conv8, up_channel_output[0], drop_out[0], 1)
        dconv2 = conv_upsample(dconv1, up_channel_output[1], drop_out[1], 2)
        dconv3 = conv_upsample(dconv2, up_channel_output[2], drop_out[2], 3)
        dconv4 = conv_upsample(dconv3, up_channel_output[3], drop_out[3], 4)
        dconv5 = conv_upsample(dconv4, up_channel_output[4], drop_out[4], 5)
        dconv6 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv5, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[0])], axis=3), up_channel_output[5], drop_out[5], 6)
        dconv7 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv6, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[1])], axis=3), up_channel_output[6], drop_out[6], 7)
        dconv8 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv7, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[2])], axis=3), up_channel_output[7], drop_out[7], 8)

        #final_tanh
        T_x = finalTanH(dconv8)

        return T_x

    # input_tensor x : to feed as Fake 
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256, channels]) # batch_size x Height x Width x N_w  

    # generated tensor T(x)
    T_x = T(x)

    # Ground_truth tensor Y : to feed as Real 
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256, 3]) # just a capture of video frame 


    # define sheudo Discriminator 
    def D(x, to_be_discriminated): #truth is either T(x) or GroudnTruth with a shape [256 x 256 x 3]
        sheudo_prob = np.float32(np.random.uniform(low=0., high=1.)) 
        return sheudo_prob

    theta_D = [] #tf.Variables of Discriminator 

    # Discrminated Result
    D_real = D(Y)
    D_fake = D(T_x)

    # Define loss 
    E_cGAN = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_real)+ tf.log(1. - D_fake))
    E_l1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm((Y-T_x)))
    Loss = EcGAN + lambda_*E_l1

    # Optimizer
    D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(-Loss, var_list=theta_D)   # Only update D(X)'s parameters, so var_list = theta_D
    T_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(Loss, var_list=theta_T)   # Only update G(X)'s parameters, so var_list = theta_T


    ####TEST####
    # define sheudo_input for testing
    sheudo_x = np.float32(np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=[16, 256,256, 99]))
    sheudo_Y = np.float32(np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=[16, 256,256, 3]))


    ####Run#### 

    init_g = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_g)
        sess.run(output_tensor,  feed_dict={x: sheudo_input Y: sheudo_Y})
```

Answer (score 0):

In `GANs` you have to train some parameters, freeze them and train some other which this operation may occur multiple times. You can do the following sequence of operations.

Specify all generator related variables inside their corresponding variable scope and after that access them using [`tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection). After that, during training, you can pass these variables as the trainable parameters of your optimiser by setting the `var_list` of the `minimize` method. You can also take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35298326/5120235).

If you want to get all the trainable variables, you can get all of them inside of a list using [`tf.trainable_variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801016/5120235) method.

Maybe it worth looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40736859/5120235) for other aspects for freezing variables.

You can also take a look at [`Hvass-Labs`](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/12_Adversarial_Noise_MNIST.ipynb)'s implementation of adversarial networks. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/11_gan.py) too.